# Ошибка при попытке открыть приложение написанное на PyQt5 и Qt Designer из PySide2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2, qt-designer

Вообщем я сделал приложение (конвертер валют) на Python и PyQt5 (интерфейс делал в Qt Designer, который взял из PySide2(так как при установке PyQt5 и PyQt5-tools там где должен лежать Qt Designer.exe был не рабочий Qt Designer.dll), так вот, я зделал интерфейс сохранил всё в одну папку (иконки, интерфейс), конвертировал интерфейс из .ui в .py файл, написал код в который имортировал всё что нужно, сделал небольшое дополнение в интерфейс, ещё даже не зделав функцию конвертации (я делал конвертер валют), запускаю, и выходит ошибка! Я проверял всё, вроде должно работать, но не работает, помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо)

Вот код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter

class CurrencyConv(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CurrencyConv, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.init_Ui()

    def init_Ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Currency Converter')

        self.ui.input_currency.setPlaceholderText('Из валюты:')
        self.ui.input_amout.setPlaceholderText('Сколько у меня есть:')
        self.ui.output_currency.setPlaceholderText('В валюту: ')
        self.ui.output_amout.setPlaceholderText('Сколько я получу:')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = CurrencyConv()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

А вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    application = CurrencyConv()
  File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
    super(CurrencyConv(), self).__init__()
  File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
    super(CurrencyConv(), self).__init__()
  File "main.py", line 10, in __init__
    super(CurrencyConv(), self).__init__()
  [Previous line repeated 496 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: покажите пожалуйста модуль `ui.py` и импорты в модуле `currency_converter.py`

Comment: Вам предоставили два ответа. Выберите один из ответов, который вам помог решить проблему и отметьте его как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка из-за рекурсивного вызов конструктора самого себя

Замените

```
super(CurrencyConv, self).__init__()
```

на

```
super(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, self).__init__()
```

а лучше вовсе **не указывать тип предка:**

```
super().__init__()
```

Comment: Одну ошибку исправило, но не все. 

Вот ошибка после изменения кода: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
         application = CurrencyConv()
       File "main.py", line 12, in __init__
         self.init_Ui()
       File "main.py", line 17, in init_Ui
         self.ui.input_currency.setPlaceholderText('Из валюты:')
     AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'input_currency'

Comment: В `Ui_MainWindow` нет виджета `input_currency`. Добавьте в вопрос `Ui_MainWindow`

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что вы в каком-то из модулей вставили лишний или не нужный импорт.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from q1207374_ui import Ui_MainWindow
#? from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter


class CurrencyConv(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CurrencyConv, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.init_Ui()

    def init_Ui(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Currency Converter')

        self.ui.input_currency.setPlaceholderText('Из валюты:')
        self.ui.input_amout.setPlaceholderText('Сколько у меня есть:')
        self.ui.output_currency.setPlaceholderText('В валюту: ')
        self.ui.output_amout.setPlaceholderText('Сколько я получу:')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = CurrencyConv()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**q1207374_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(265, 320)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.input_currency = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_currency.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 30, 113, 20))
        self.input_currency.setObjectName("input_currency")
        self.input_amout = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.input_amout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 70, 113, 20))
        self.input_amout.setObjectName("input_amout")
        self.output_currency = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_currency.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 120, 113, 20))
        self.output_currency.setObjectName("output_currency")
        self.output_amout = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_amout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 170, 113, 20))
        self.output_amout.setObjectName("output_amout")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 265, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется я нашёл решение проблемы - я скопипастил из конвертированого .ui файла в .py код, отвечающий за интрефейс в main.py, и уже там буду писать дополнения)

Comment: @JustRizer_   Мне кажется, что вы в каком-то из модулей вставили лишний или не нужный импорт. Покажите пожалуйста модуль `ui.py` и импорты в модуле `currency_converter.py`

Comment: Не получается, он довольно большой

Comment: @JustRizer_ вы смотрели и пробовали мой пример? Что у вас большое ? Покажите ИМПОРТЫ модулей `ui.py` и `currency_converter.py`

Comment: Всё, код работает)